# What is the difference between Page.IsPostBack and Page.IsCallBack?

Tags: asp.net, postback, callback, page-lifecycle

I've recently ran into some code that checks `Page.IsCallBack` but I wasn't sure how it is different from `Page.IsPostBack`. Can anyone enlighten me?

**Edit**: Are they mutually exclusive or can both occur at the same time in a given situation?

Comment: Given the answers so far, a better question might be what's the difference between IsCallback and IsAsync?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Page.IsCallBack**

> It is getting a value indicating whether the page request is the result of a call back. Its a special postback, so a round-trip always occurs; however, unlike the classic postback, the script callback doesn't redraw the whole page. *ViewState is not updated* during a callback, it is for postback.

**Page.IsPostBack**

> Checks whether the Page is accessing the server for the first time or not. Unlike the IsCallBack, the ViewState is updated

Refer to [Page Life Cycle](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_server_doc/developer/adf/pagepost_clientcall.htm) for more detail that shows a diagram illustrating the **sequence of events**

**Edit -** To answer your new question

> Page.IsPostback property will return true for both request types.  The Page.IsCallback property will return true only when the request is a client callback

Comment: I like your answer but could you rephrase your 2nd quote so it is cleaner? Thanks.

Comment: Link now broken. Maybe should be http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/ADF/ajax_callback.htm ?

Answer (score 33):

[`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) is true when the page is posted via a form method

[`IsCallBack`](http://forums.asp.net/p/1007585/1339737.aspx) is true when the page has been called back from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 6):

A callback is a special postback, so a round-trip always occurs; however, unlike the classic postback, the script callback doesn't redraw the whole page. ViewState is not updated during a callback, it is for postback.

More info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724003925/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AaronLi/archive/2007/04/20/111817.aspx):

Comment: In a callback, can you mainuplate the Response to return a file(like csv) for the user to download?

Answer (score 6):

A postback is when the form is posted back to itself, either by clicking a submit button or through Javascript (like AutoPostback controls)

A callback is when an AJAX Control calls a method on the page as part of an ajax request

Comment: Can you give some examples of relevant controls that would issue a callback?

Answer (score 0):

Page.IsPostBack 
Checks whether the Page is accessing the server for the first time or not. Unlike the IsCallBack, the ViewState is updated