# every time IsCallback is getting fasle

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my Mark up Page where I have a Button to search data from DB and display in the Grid

And this is my code behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LblInfo.Text = "Page Loaded";
    }

    if (IsCallback)
    {
        LblInfo.Text = "Page Called Back";
    }
```

please explain why every time  IsCallback = fasle?

Comment: Hard to say more considering information you've provided. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx): `true if the page request is the result of a callback; otherwise, false.`

Comment: Callbacks aren't the same as postbacks...

Answer (score 4):

`IsCallBack` is a special kind of *postback*.

The only time `IsCallBack` is going to be true is if `IsPostBack` is also true.

Therefore their is no way to get to your "Page Called Back" code.  See [What is the difference between Page.IsPostBack and Page.IsCallBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760912/what-is-the-difference-between-page-ispostback-and-page-iscallback)

The two variables can result in exactly 3 conditions:

- IsPostBack and IsCallBack are both false: initial page load.
- IsPostBack is true; IsCallBack is false: full postback occurred.
- IsPostBack is true; IsCallBack is true: request came from ajax.

There is no situation in which IsPostBack will be false and IsCallBack will be true.

So your code should be:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    { 
        LblInfo.Text = "Initial Page Loaded"; 
    } 
} else {
    if (IsCallback) 
    { 
        LblInfo.Text = "Page Called Back"; 
    } else {
        LblInfo.Text = "Page Posted Back";
    }
}
```