# What is the difference between IsPostBack, IsAsync and IsCallback?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, postback, asp.net-4.0

I was writing code in `Page_Load` and I used `IsPostBack` in the first place but then I came across with `IsAsync` and `IsCallback` properties. I started to think and they look like somewhat the same. From google I found some information:

1. `IsPostBack` is true when the page is posted via a form method, *I agree 100%*.
2. `IsCallBack` is true when the page has been called back from an AJAX call, *Then for what purpose IsAsync is for?*
   *from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx)* "`IsCallBack`: Gets a value that indicates whether the page request is the result of a callback."
3. `IsAsync` when an ASP.net AJAX partial update is made ,its an Asynchronous postback.

However I still have some questions:

1. What is a callback and how it is different from a postback.
2. Clearly differentiate among IsPostBack, IsAsync and IsCallback.
3. Currently I'm working on a WebApp, which can perform postBack through jQuery Ajax. So to identify the jQuery Ajax I should use IsPostBack.

### Useful links:

[Difference between IsCallback and IsPostback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760912/what-is-the-difference-between-page-ispostback-and-page-iscallback)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `IsAsync` is independent of the type of request made by the client and its used to identify a page that is processed asynchronously as described in the documentation:

> Gets a value indicating whether the page is processed asynchronously.

You can read more about asynchronous pages in this MSDN Magazine article [Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx#S2).

The `IsCallback` is used to identify a client callback, see [Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) and finally the `IsPostback` identifies a request that resulted from the submission of the form associated with the page. The `IsPostback` by itself cannot be used to identify a postback that will fully render the page from one that will do a partial rendering, for example, if you are using an `UpdatePanel`.

In order to identify a postback request that will only perform partial rendering you will need to check that `IsPostback` is true and `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack` is also true.

Also of interest to this topic [How to: Determine How ASP.NET Web Pages Were Invoked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178141.aspx).

Comment: How does <ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack> relate to <Page.IsAsync>?

Comment: It doesn't, they are independent and are used to check non related features. You can think of `Page.IsAsync` as information on how the page is processed on the server independently of the type of client request that triggered the page processing.