# Difference between IsPostBack, IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Can someone point me to a link which explains difference between IsPostBack, IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack in ASP.NET?

I have googled but didn’t get exact information.

Found below link for difference between IsPostBack, IsCallback.
[What is the difference between Page.IsPostBack and Page.IsCallBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760912/what-is-the-difference-between-page-ispostback-and-page-iscallback)

Thanks,
Balu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) `IsPostBack`: "A postback is a request sent from a client to server from the same page, user is already working with." ASP.NET was introduced with a mechanism to post an `HTTP POST` request back to the same page. It’s basically posting a complete page back to server (i.e. sending all of its data) on same page. So, the whole page is refreshed.

2) `IsCallBack`: “A callback is generally a call for execution of a function after another function has completed.” But if we try to differentiate it from a postback then we can say: It’s a call made to the server to receive specific data instead of whole page refresh like a postback. In ASP.NET, its achieved using `AJAX`, that makes a call to server and updating a part of the page with specific data received.

3) `IsCrossPagePostBack`: “Gets a value indicating whether the page is involved in a cross-page postback or not." It's a different feature from "`IsPostBack`" and "`IsCalBack`" because It's generally used when we need to get the data from previous page

[Reference Link](http://forums.asp.net/p/2011889/5787175.aspx?Difference%20between%20IsCallBack%20IsPostBack%20IscrossPagePostBack%20and%20whent%20use%20Which%20One%20)

Comment: Can you explain 3. a bit more? A short example would be helpful.

Comment: Hi modix, Please find below link. I hope this will help you. http://forums.asp.net/t/1054392.aspx?Difference+b+w+IsPostBack+and+IsCrossPagePostBack            https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.page.iscrosspagepostback.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233555/IsCrossPagePostBack-Cross-page-PostBack